# Windows 10 overriding my Audio driver

Tags: windows, audio, drivers

I keep having issues with the audio driver since the last windows update.

I tried to reinstall the driver directly by using the installer provided by Realtek.
Eveything goes well until I restart windows to complete the installation.

I have sound & mic for like 5 seconds, then I notice in the device manager that Windows keeps reinstalling/updating the sound driver.

I disabled windows update, I disabled automatic download of manufacturer apps, I even disabled the internet connection.

I can't find a way to properly do this, no forum or microsoft answer has helped so far.

Comment: Windows tends to do that if the drivers you're trying to install are older than the ones in the update.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia I was thinking that is the case, but it isn't. I downloaded the latest driver. Also it still doesn't explain why with disabled update and disabled download for manufacturer apps it stills overwrites the driver. It's like it's ignoring the settings.